# Eslint plugin for checking text bodies

Tags: typescript, jsx, eslint

I tend to accidentally hard code some strings like the name of the application into error messages. I have the name available in a const but I forget to use the const and write the name of the application in a JSX Element or a TypeScript string. The project uses ESLint for code validation. Does ESLint have some rule or plugin for checking JSX Element and TypeScript string contents for forbidden words/sentences?